# Opentelemetry collector receiver ssl + C#

Tags: c#, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I have an opentelemetry collector which I want to secure using tls. I have generated a certificate and a key file which I am supplying in the yaml file:

```
receivers:
otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:30004
        tls:
          cert_file: domainlong.crt
          key_file: domainlong.key
extensions:
  health_check:
    endpoint: localhost:30008
exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug
  otlp/insecure:
    tls:
      insecure: true
    endpoint: localhost:30007
service:
  extensions: health_check
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: otlp
      exporters: otlp/insecure
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: debug
      encoding: json
      output_paths: .\otelCollector.log.json
...
```

I am sending traces to that endpoing using the following code in c#:

```
            var lovTraceProvider = Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder()
            .AddSource("OpenTelemetryCollector")
            .SetResourceBuilder(
                ResourceBuilder.CreateDefault()
                    .AddService(serviceName: "OpenTelemetryCollector"))
            .AddConsoleExporter()
            .AddOtlpExporter(lovOplt =>
            {
                lovOplt.Protocol = OtlpExportProtocol.Grpc;
                lovOplt.Endpoint = new Uri("https://localhost:30004");
            })
            .Build();

            var lovFirstTrace = lovActivitySource.StartActivity("First trace");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var lovFirstActivity = lovActivitySource.StartActivity("Trace binnen for loop");
                lovFirstActivity?.AddEvent(new ActivityEvent($"Dit is trace {i} binnen activity {i}"));
                lovFirstActivity.Stop();
            }
            lovFirstTrace.Stop();
```

Without SSL this works, but if I turn on ssl it doesn't.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It appears that you are configuring your collector with a certificate. Your issue may be related to https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/issues/3393. If the the certificate is self-signed or not trusted, you could add it as a trusted certificate and SSL should work.